# Create a .bat file that takes user inputs in command prompt and saves it to a text file

Tags: batch-file, input, terminal, cmd

I need to create a .bat file that takes user inputs in command prompt and saves it to a text file.

In command prompt it would like:

```
What is the path: "C:\Users\21241\Desktop\test"
Number of times to run: "7"
```

In the text file it would look like:

```
User_input_Path: C:\Users\21241\Desktop\test
Num_run_time: 7
```

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off&cls
set /p $path=What is the path: 
set /p $num=Number of times to run: 


(echo User_input_Path: %$path%
 echo Num_run_time: %$num%)>your_text_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET /P pat=What is the path:
SET /P num=Number of times to run:
echo User_input_Path: %pat% > txt.txt
echo Num_run_time: %num% > txt.txt
```

Not on windows so can't test, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to run this once:

```
@echo off

SET /P Path="What is the path: "
SET /P Num="Number of times to run: "

ECHO What is the path: %Path% > sample.txt
ECHO Number of times to run: %Num% > sample.txt
```

However if you are wanting "Number of times to run" to be the number of times the user inputs a path, then:

```
@echo off
SET /P Num="Number of times to run: "

SET Count=1
IF %Num% NEQ %Count% (
    SET /P Path="What is the path: "
    ECHO What is the path: %Path% > sample.txt

    SET /A Count=Count+1
) ELSE exit
```

Comment: _please_ don't use `path` as a variable name. It's a systemvariable and changing it can (and probably will) lead to failures.